# Java : Random Position of JButton

Tags: java, swing, location, jbutton

I want to set the location of JButtons with coordinates but how to make each button don't "touch" the others? The Layout must be null !!! I tried the method contains and with Rectangle but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use Layout manager such as FlowLayout?

Comment: The Layout manager isn't random coordinates, I don't want specific location such the row!!! 
Thanks for the answer

Comment: If each button coordinates are set as random - then you need to calculate the bounds on your own. Each button can be randomly placed on a distinct rectangle zone.

Comment: I will try this..
Thanks!!!

Comment: *"The Layout must be null !!!"* The layout must **not** be null!!! Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: Don't edit the title of the question with "Solved" or attribute the solution in the question. Instead, [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.

Comment: @user1803551 thanks for that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `intersects()`, not `contains()`. `contains()` will only return `true` if `comp1` **entirely** contains `comp2`. Here is an example that continues to add new `JButton`'s at a random position, as long as they don't intersect another `Component`. (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVC5A.gif) for a preview)

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Example {

    private final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 100;
    private final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 20;

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null);

        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            Random random = new Random();

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JButton button = new JButton("Button");
                button.setBounds(random.nextInt(frame.getContentPane().getWidth() - BUTTON_WIDTH),
                        random.nextInt(frame.getContentPane().getHeight() - BUTTON_HEIGHT), BUTTON_WIDTH,
                        BUTTON_HEIGHT);
                for (int tries = 0; tries < 50; tries++) {
                    if (intersectsComponent(button, frame.getContentPane().getComponents())) {
                        button.setBounds(random.nextInt(frame.getContentPane().getWidth() - BUTTON_WIDTH),
                                random.nextInt(frame.getContentPane().getHeight() - BUTTON_HEIGHT), BUTTON_WIDTH,
                                BUTTON_HEIGHT);
                    } else {
                        frame.add(button);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public boolean intersectsComponent(Component component, Component[] components) {
        for (Component c : components) {
            if (c.getBounds().intersects(component.getBounds())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `GridLayout` and by toggling with `JButton.setVisible( true / false )`, then OPs requirement is completed ..., thats just my (helocopter) view

Comment: @mKorbel I agree that that is probably the better solution. However, OP stated *"The Layout **must** be null"*, so I guess this ('absolutely' random positions) is what he was asking for.

Comment: @LuxxMiner Thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: @EagleJ You're welcome! Btw, please consider to accept the most helpful answer, so others who view this post will instantly know which was the best answer :)

Comment: Luxx, I managed to "convince" him to do that in the question's comments section ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a total space of H pixels by W pixels. 
You can divide this space to a grid of 10 by 10.
Each "slot" is now H/10 by W/10.
Now you can create 100 buttons which do not collide using random setBounds(...) in each slot using a null layout.
Each JButton has its own space and you still get semi-randomness.

Note that MadProgrammer would prolly tell you it's a very bad idea to use null layouts.

**EDIT:**
Not **only** MadProgrammer.

Disclaimer:
I did once used a null layout for JDekstopPane. 
I still have this line of code with me.
The rest 1M or so lines of code are free of such rebellious concepts.

Comment: upvote for referencing MadProgrammer

Comment: Every GUI (not only Swing) person would tell you not to use null layouts.